# What is the next prime number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

Given an integer

\begin{equation*}
N~\text{such that}~N\leq 10^{18}, 
\end{equation*}

what is the next prime number after this number? What approach should I use to solve this problem?

(Problem link: http://www.spoj.com/problems/NAJPLNP/cstart=10 )

Comment: Make a list of odd numbers larger than $N$ that end with a $1, 3, 7$ or $9$ and test them subsequently, until you find one that is prime.

Comment: Will a probabilistic algorithm do?  How certain do you need to be that it is prime?  In any case, these algorithms can show with certainty what is *not* prime.  For the rest, you could probably set up a quadratic number sieve to verify primality.

Comment: Wouldn't that be too much complex? I mean for like there may be 100 or 1000 testcases. @m-wind

Comment: The next prime number must be prime. I know how sieve algorithm works. But don't know anything about "Quadratic Number Sieve". Can you explain how should it work please? @Kyle Miller

Comment: No, I don't think so. If you have PC at your disposal and a good algorithm, the actual evaluation should not take no more than a few seconds.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of this?  The answer greatly depends on what your goal is.

Comment: http://www.spoj.com/problems/NAJPLNP/cstart=10
I was trying to solve this problem. Read the statements of the problem please. @KyleMiller

Comment: @Kyle: What's a quadratic number sieve? There is a quadratic sieve and a number field sieve that I know of, but those are for factorization -- they are not much use for proving primality.

Answer (score 1):

See:  [Given $N$, what is the next prime $p$ greater than $N$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867686/given-n-what-is-the-next-prime-p-greater-than-n)

Your question seems more programming related than mathematics.  Given your range, you can use a deterministic Miller-Rabin test which will be relatively easy to code, quite fast since you need at most 7 bases, and correct (not probabilistic).  Use a simple trial division pre-test to quickly weed out small factors.

Code examples for M-R can be found at [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test) for many languages.  Some examples use deterministic sets, but with the exception of Julia and Perl, they're using inferior sets from 1993.

Deterministic bases good to various limits can be found at [Best Known SPRP bases sets](http://miller-rabin.appspot.com/).

While not necessary for your example, using either hashed M-R tests or a BPSW test (Miller-Rabin base 2 plus a strong Lucas test) can be somewhat faster albeit more complicated.  There is also faster C code for these tests than shown on RosettaCode (the best bases link shows a couple examples).  These allow `next_prime` to average only a couple microseconds in the $10^{18}$ range and 5-10x less than that for 32-bit inputs.

---

In more detail, I would have an `is_prime` function that took a 64-bit input, answered small cases immediately (e.g. $n < 11$) followed by simple divisibility tests (if $n$ mod 2,3,5,7 is $0$ then return false; again for a few more small primes (taking care with small inputs)), followed by calling the M-R or BPSW function with appropriate arguments.  Your main program can just trivially increment $n$ until this `is_prime` function returns true.

If you want to get a bit fancier, you could make your main loop use a wheel (skip multiples of 2 or 2/3 or 2/3/5 or 2/3/5/7) but this complicates things for not a lot of gain.  You could also do a partial sieve on a range past $n$, but I haven't found this faster until 120-bit input -- quite a bit larger than your limit.  Neither of these seem at all necessary for your example.